# appended select option is viewable in HTML but not detectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button that will update my `select`. Here is the code:

```
$("#add_row").on('click', function(){
        var table = $("#ingredients_info_table");
        var count_table_tbody_tr = $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr").length;
        var row_id = count_table_tbody_tr + (Math.floor(Math.random()*1000));

        var html = '<tr id="row_'+row_id+'"><td><select class="form-control" data-row-id="row_'+row_id+'" id="ingredient_'+row_id+'" name="ingredient[]" onchange="getIngredientAmount(\''+row_id+'\')" style="width:100%;" required><option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>'
        html += '</select>'+'</td><td><label for="amount"><i id="amount_unit_'+row_id+'" >Amount Unit</i> x</label><input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount_'+row_id+'" class="form-control" required style="display: inline-block;"></td>'+
        '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeRow(\''+row_id+'\')"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>'+
        '</tr>';

        $.ajax({
            url: "../api/ajax/getInventory.php",
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(response2){
                // console.log(response2["data"]);
                // console.log(Object.keys(response2["data"][0]).length);
                for (var i = 0; i < response2["data"].length; i++) {
                    $("select#ingredient_"+row_id).append('<option value="'+response2['data'][i][0]+'">'+response2['data'][i][1]+'</option>');
                    $("select#ingredient_"+row_id).trigger('chosen:updated').change();
                }
            }
        });

        if(count_table_tbody_tr >= 1) {
            $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr:last").after(html);
        }
        else {
            $("#ingredients_info_table tbody").html(html);
        }
    });
```

[It is working properly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/finTz.jpg) The dropdown list is updated.

The problem here is whenever I tried to `console.log()` the selector for the option, it appears as if the selector is empty, but based on the [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/finTz.jpg), the dropdown menu is updated.

Here is the `console.log()`:

```
console.log($('#ingredients_info_table tbody tr[id^="row_"]:last td select').html());
```

And here is the output for the `console.log()`:

```
<option value="" selected="" disabled="" hidden=""></option>
//this empty option is statically inserted, not dynamic.
```

My question is, how should I display or find the updated set of options after it is dynamically updated (after the `.append()` is used) so that I could use those updated elements.

Comment: where are you doing the console.log()?  If you are doing it inside the `success` callback, it should work.  if you are doing it after the ajax block, it will be blank.

Comment: @AlanP. I am doing it inside another `ajax` block.

Comment: In the code you shared, put the `if/else` code above the `$.ajax` code to clarify things.  Then try putting the console.log in THIS ajax calls `success` callback, and see what it says.  You have to be sure the that THIS ajax code has finished before the other ajax block you speak of gets called.  T

Comment: what's the condition of the `if/else` statament?

Comment: Your if else from the snippet in the original post

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is empty because you are calling it before the data is populated through ajax. You have to get your html inside `success` callback then call the other ajax block.

Also you don't have to count the number of rows before insertion. You can use `.append()` which will always insert after all children.

See this example:

```js
$("#add_row").on('click', function() {
  var table = $("#ingredients_info_table");
  var count_table_tbody_tr = $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr").length;

  var row_id = count_table_tbody_tr + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));

  var html = `
 <tr id="row_${row_id}">
  <td><select class="form-control" data-row-id="row_${row_id}" id="ingredient_${row_id}" name="ingredient[]" onchange="getIngredientAmount(${row_id})" style="width:100%;" required>
      <option value="" selected disabled hidden></option>
    </select>
  </td>
  <td>
    <label for="amount"><i id="amount_unit_${row_id}">Amount Unit</i> x</label>
    <input type="number" name="amount[]" id="amount_${row_id}" class="form-control" required style="display: inline-block;">
  </td>
  <td>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="removeRow(${row_id})"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
  </td>
</tr>
`;

  $("#ingredients_info_table tbody").append(html);

  $.ajax({
    url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/",
    type: "get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response2) {
      console.log(response2.length);
      // console.log(response2["data"]);
      // console.log(Object.keys(response2["data"][0]).length);
      for (var i = 0; i < response2.length; i++) {
        $("select#ingredient_" + row_id).append('<option value="' + response2[i]['id'] + '">' + response2[i]['title'] + '</option>');
        //$("select#ingredient_" + row_id).trigger('chosen:updated').change();
      }


      console.log($('#ingredients_info_table tbody tr[id^="row_"]:last td select').html());

    }
  });

  // no need for this code
  /*  if (count_table_tbody_tr >= 1) {
      $("#ingredients_info_table tbody tr:last").after(html);
    } else {
      $("#ingredients_info_table tbody").html(html);
    }*/





});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='ingredients_info_table'>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>

<div id='add_row'>
  Add Row
</div>
```